# converting hours: minutes javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me solve the following problem in javascript(its in ruby below)?
thank you!

Write a method that will take in a number of minutes, and returns a string that formats the number into `hours:minutes`.

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hours = 0

  while minutes >= 60
    hours += 1
    minutes -= 60
  end

  if minutes < 10
    minutes_s = "0" + minutes.to_s
  else
    minutes_s = minutes.to_s
  end

  return hours.to_s + ":" + minutes_s
end
```

Comment: how much javascript do you know? `const time_conversion = (minutes) => Math.floor(minutes/60).toString() + ':' + ('0' + (minutes % 60)).substr(-2);`

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 0):

This is it in Javascript:

```js
function time_conversion(minutes) {

  var hours = 0;

  while (minutes >= 60) {
    hours += 1;
    minutes -= 60;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes_s = "0" + minutes;
  }
  else {
    minutes_s = minutes;
  }
  return hours + ":" + minutes_s;
}

console.log(time_conversion(566));
```

Comment: Pretty sure calling toString() is unnecessary here since you're concatenating with a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple change from your code to JavaScript.

```
function time_conversion(minutes) {

  var hours = 0;

  while(minutes >= 60){
    hours++;
    minutes -= 60;
  }

  if(minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  } 

  return hours+ ":" + minutes;
}
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in the ruby code is pointless. You can use the modulus operator

```
hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60)
minutes = minutes % 60
```